# MIPS factorial function that checks if it can return the value in a word

Tags: assembly, mips

Hi so I'm studying for an exam and have been working my way through old exams and found this task.

"Write a MIPS function that calculates n!(n!=1*2*3...*n) and returns the result in a word. The function should also return information which indicates if n! can be represented in a word or not"

I wrote the function for the first part that just calculates n! . Not really sure what it means to return it in a word, I stored it in $v0 and then added jr $ra to return to caller. I'm also uncertain what the second part of the question wants. Am I to check if $v0 is larger than 2,147,483,647 and return 0 as false and 1 as true?

Help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Of course you can't check that directly :) Depending on the assignment you can just check the input, knowing which one will cross over. Alternatively, at each step make sure the new value is bigger than the previous, if not, an overflow occurred.

Comment: @Jester Not sure what you mean by cross over. It's a pen and paper exam so not any ways to check by trial and error.

Comment: Then go with the second option.

Comment: @Jester I think the question I'm asking is what should I return to say that it can be represented in a word? As in should I put a true or false in $v1 ?

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: @Jester: MIPS32 multiplication (`MULT`) is 32x32->64 bit, so you can use `mfhi` to see if the multiplication result fits into a 32-bit word.

Comment: In general, a potential multiplication overflow can be detected by dividing the maximum possible value (say `0xFFFFFFFF`) by the multiplier. If the quotient is less than the other multiplier, then the multiplication will overflow. But checking that the next product is greater than the previous (@Jester) is a faulty method.

Comment: @EOF great that's simple then

Comment: @Weather Vane yeah looks like I messed that up.

Comment: @JohnDoe "what should I return to indicate the result overflowed?" A value that cannot be a factorial, for example `0`. Note that `0! = 1`.

Comment: ...so the answer could be, return the factorial, or 0.

Comment: what about testing the INPUT for being larger than 12 ? I cannot see you have to really calculate the n! to find out if it will fit or not. something like `if (n>12) return 0 else return n!;`